# When does Google Maps load its data?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Say I have a `GoogleMap` in an `Activity` but set its `visibility` to `gone`: will it load data (and therefore use bandwidth) or will it only load data when it becomes visible to the user?

I'm asking because I want to only show the map when the user is on wifi and the question is if setting `visibility` to gone will `effectively` save the bandwidth that the map data would use.

Comment: So, would you like to show your map when wifi is enabled? otherwise Map will not show ? Please clarify this thing

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. The question is if not showing the map (with visibility gone) will prevent it from loading data from Google.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After testing this with a test project and Eclipse's network statistics I can say the following:

The `GoogleMap` loads its data wether or not it is visible. Placing it within a layout and setting `visibility` of the layout to `gone` in the XML, the map still loads its data. No more network activity was done when programmatically setting the `visibility` to `visible` afterwards. Same goes when setting the initial `visibility` to `invisible`.

My approach to not having a GoogleMap (and the associated network traffic) when the user is on mobile data will probably be to programmatically add the `GoogleMap` only when the user is on wifi.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the ConnectivityManager  to get the state of the Wifi adapter.  From there you can [check if it is connected or even available](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html).

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
    // show the map
}
else {
   Toast.makeText(this,"Not connected to Wifi",Toast.Length_SHORT).show();
}
```

Also you need to add: `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` to your AndroidManifest.xml for this to work.